# Is this an nginx proxy_cache bug?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

I have a very simple proxy config:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=s3-images-cache:50m inactive=1M max_size=1000m;
    proxy_temp_path /var/www/cache/tmp;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name images.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_cache s3-images-cache;
            proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_purge_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid any 1y;
            proxy_pass http://images-example.s3.amazonaws.com;
            add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 404 = @no_image;
        }

        location @no_image {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}
```

Now follow me here:

1. Let's request /image.jpg.
2. Request is sent to proxy for /image.jpg (does not exists yet).
3. Backend responds with 404.
4. "proxy_intercept_errors on" kicks in and "error_page 404 = @no_image" is called.
5. Nginx returns 403.
6. Do another request for same image and see that "X-Cache: HIT" is set. We are clearly hitting proxy cache.

But, if we check /var/www/cache/ folder at this time we will see that there is no cache item created for this request. So does it mean Nginx keeps the cache for it in memory and forgot to write to file?

7. Let's upload /image.jpg to backend.
8. Now do "PURGE-CACHE: 1" request to that image. We see that now we get the image instead of 403 with "X-Cache: BYPASS" header present. Good.

If we check /var/www/cache/ we will see that the cache file is now finally created for this request. Looking inside the cached file we see that it is our image.

9. Now here is the problem: lets request /image.jpg again with a normal GET request. We should get the newly uploaded image right?
10. Nginx returns 403 with "X-Cache: HIT". Why? It seems like it's hitting the cache but returning something else not what is in /var/www/cache folder?? How?

My only explanation to this is it seems that Nginx is caching the response in memory and doesn't write to file when we are hitting error with our custom error_page in the proxied responses. Furthermore when using proxy_cache_bypass it does not overwrite in-memory cache, so that subsequent requests to the same item will be using old cache which is stored in memory and not the new one created in the cache folder.

Could someone please let me know if I am doing something wrong or this really is a bug. Spent last 3 days fighting this.

**UPDATE:** Backend returns normal set of headers you would would expect from S3 in both 200 and 404 responses:

**404**

```
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Fri, 20 Nov 2015 07:41:39 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
x-amz-id-2:bH8L/1dOVGShsGJdZZ/zS/X6UkHS+KMAxDxnPvOkIalpPphFJXr9zZ1RiV6L2a13NXoZ3QdCOeE=
x-amz-request-id:D66FDBFAA9643252
```

**200**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10533
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Fri, 20 Nov 2015 07:47:12 GMT
ETag:"061b4dae0b2bbdf4a4fa212951f4ba79"
Last-Modified:Wed, 11 Nov 2015 14:29:09 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:qsSmH/gkvql2jnj67p0vguZBXQJHfS+Yk70llBaDvbgH0xSCbvj9G9JlKn5WhWTdty0+JzApN7k=
x-amz-request-id:8CF04EA869190E63
```

Comment: "My only explanation to this is it seems that Nginx is caching the response in memory", well yes it is because you have told it to with `proxy_cache_valid any 1y`

Comment: Why is it not writing the cached item to disk?

Comment: From what you said above it does once it is on the backend server, but it then doesn't read it correctly even though it returns X-CACHE:HIT

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @DenisPshenov, what does it write to cache?  does it write the new request, or the old one?  what happens on subsequent requests?

Comment: Also, what sort of headers does your backend provide in its responses, in both 200 OK and 404 Not Found cases?

Comment: At step 8 it returns newly uploaded image with "X-Cache: BYPASS" and writes the new response to disk (cache) which is this new image. On subsequent normal GET requests it does not read the cache from disk but rather reads from in-memory cache (my hypothesis) so doesn't return cached image and keeps returning 403 with "X-Cache: HIT" header. Please check updated answer to see what headers are returned from backend.